# Hide control on word document save

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Can anybody shed some light on how to hide a control on save for a word document? So far, I have been able to capture the save event, but not able to access the control inside the class module. I can do it in code behind as `me.Label1.caption="Test"`.

Comment: I'm confused - what do you mean word document save? Like they use an upload control to upload a word document?

Comment: say i have a word template form with button on it and i want to hide the button on document save event. Simply on Menu File-> Save As i want the button to hide on Output copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By putting my code in the document close event I was able to get it working.